# How to develop with PYSPARK locally and run on Spark Cluster?

Tags: python, eclipse, apache-spark, pyspark, development-environment

I'm new to Spark.I installed a Spark 2.3.0 in Stand-Alone-Mode on an Ubuntu 16.04.3 server. That runs well so far. Now I would like to start developing with pyspark because I've got more experience using python than scala.

Ok. Even after using google for a while I'm not sure how I should setup my development environment. My local machine is a windows 10 laptop with eclipse neon and pydev configured. What are the neccessary steps to set ist up that I can develop in a local context and submit my modules to the spark cluster on my server?

Thank for helping.

Answer (score 0):

use [spark-submit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) to run locally or on a cluster.  There are many online tutorials for this.  I like the [AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/submitting-user-applications-with-spark-submit/) which explains the architecture, has sample spark code, and gives examples of local and remote commands.  Even if you are not using AWS EMR the basics are the same.

give it a try and let us know how it goes